# The difference between universal and existential quantifiers in set abstractions

Tags: discrete-mathematics, elementary-set-theory

I'm finding it difficult to differentiate between

$$\{(x,y) \mid \forall z((x,z) \in R \lor (z,y) \in S) \} $$

and

$$\{(x,y) \mid \exists z((x,z) \in R \lor (z,y) \in S) \} $$

where $R, S \subseteq A \times A$ are binary relations on a set $A$.

Could someone please give a simple example which clearly differentiates these?

Under what conditions are these sets identical, and is it always the case that $R$ and $S$ are subsets of both of them?

Answer (score 0):

Suppose $A=\mathbb{Z}$, that $R=S$ and that $xRy \iff \frac{x}{y}\in \mathbb{Z}$.

Then the second set is $A\times A$ for you can always find a $z\in \mathbb{Z}$ such that it divides $x$ or that it is divisible by $y$ (e.g. take $z=1$).

But the first set is empty, for take $(x,y)$. If $x=y$ take $z$ any non multiple of $x$. If not, take $z$ any non multiple of $y$ that does not divide $x$.

---

When will these be identical?

It's sufficient (but I don't know if necessary) that $A$ is non empty and that the first set is $A\times A$. This is because, in the case $A\neq \emptyset$ the second set contains the first one.

So, for example, if $R$ and $S$ are equivalence relations on $A$ with only one equivalence class each, the condition holds trivially.

---

It is not always the case that $R$ and $S$ are subsets of them:

Suppose that $R,S$ are equivalence relations such that the class of $a\in A$ is $\{a\}$ for both of them then $$R\cap 1\text{st set} = \{(a,a)\}$$ so if $\{(a,a)\}\subsetneq R$, then $R$ is not contained in the firs set. You can do simmilar things with $S$ and the second set.

---

---

A more human example:

Suppose $A$ is the set of all humans that have ever been born, that $(x,z)\in R$ if and only if $z$ is the father of $z$ and that $(z,y)\in S$ if and only if $z$ is the mother of $y$.

For a $(x,y)$ to be in the first set it must be the case that for all humans $z\in A$ either $x$ is $z$'s father or $z$ is $y$'s mother. So if you take a $z$ completely unrelated (in the sense of family) to $x$ and $y$, that doesn't hold. So the first set is empty for no $(x,y)$ belongs to it.

The second set however, is the whole $A\times A$ for take any $(x,y)$, then as $y$ has been born, it must have had a mother $z$ so $(z,y)\in S$ and thus $(x,y)$ belongs to the second set.

Comment: I'm afraid your mathematical examples don't help me, since I have limited grasp of the notions you base your answer on. Please can you give ordinary examples involving human beings and properties of them?

Comment: Sorry for that. Are you at least familiar with the concepts of _equivalence relation_ and _equivalence class_?

Comment: I added an example at the end. Hope it helps.

Comment: Not really. I found that explanation of how $R$ and $S$ are not necessarily subsets of the sets a little confusing.